# MailChimp for Salesforce

Tags: mail-chimp

Is there an application that can integrate Mail Chimp reports with Salesforce ?

We have installed mailchimp however it doesn't show the amount of clicks, opens for each campaign or list

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the '[MailChimp for Salesforce](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3byfEAB)' package?

It allows access to MailChimp configuration and capabilities from within Salesforce including

> - Manage MailChimp data storage options in Salesforce
> - See subscriber detail and full MailChimp activity
> - View MailChimp campaign reports and campaign share reports from within Salesforce

Another solution which also provides these capabilities is [SyncApps](http://community.cazoomi.com/cazoomi/topics/_number_sent_in_salesforce_campaign_not_updating)